# Hide repeated column data in angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjFHr.jpg)I am trying to hide repeated column data in Angular(6) material meaning:

```
 data = [
    {name: 'Bo', lastname:'Belfort', address:'street1', description:'description1'};
    {name: 'Bo', lastname:'Belfort', address:'street1', description:'description2'},
    {name: 'Tom', lastname:'Goshin', address:'street2', description:'description3'},
    {name: 'Esther', lastname:'Jermain', address:'street3', description:'description4'},
    {name: 'Tom', lastname:'Goshin', address:'street2', description:'description5'},
]
```

I tried this but failed:

```
removeDuplicates(myArr, prop) {
  myArr = this.dataSource.filteredData;
  return myArr.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
    arr.map(mapObj => mapObj[prop]).indexOf(obj[prop]) === pos;
    console.log(myArr)
  });
}
```

I would like to show the `name` and `lastname` only once for each person (leaving that column data blank) but display the address and description repeatedly.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: it needs to show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) what you tried..?

Comment: It tried this but failed:     removeDuplicates(myArr, prop) {
         myArr = this.dataSource.filteredData;
        return myArr.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
             arr.map(mapObj => mapObj[prop]).indexOf(obj[prop]) === pos;
            console.log(myArr)

        });
    }

Comment: Include that in your question

Comment: @gfos,@Irf i just updated the question

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You want to remove duplicate items from the array?

Comment: Please indicate what you're current code produces, and how that differs from what you *want* or to produce. You need to provide an example of what you're looking for to be clear. Go to the Help section, and revert "How to a ask..", and "Minimum Viable Example". Then `edit ` your question appropriately, so we Can Efficiently Help You.

Comment: @ Chris Barr, I want to display the rows without repeating the name for example, just use Belfort once as a header row when repeated then leaving the column row underneath blank( still display the address and description for that row )

Comment: Possible repetition of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51088882/how-to-remove-objects-with-the-same-key-and-value-pair-in-arrays
Please refer to it for help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove objects with the same key and value pair in arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51088882/how-to-remove-objects-with-the-same-key-and-value-pair-in-arrays)

Comment: I just included a picture to show the expected result. not that I am trying to remove all the duplicated object but just hide the repeated data for name and lastname columns. Sorry if the post was not clear enough, I just signed up to use stack

Comment: Where did you call the function `removeDuplicates`?

Comment: in the onInit function

Comment: Could you show relevant html code? I suppose that it didn't update the data after filtering.